# Cannot serialize member System.Exception.Data of type System.Collections.IDictionary, because it implements IDictionary.

Tags: silverlight, visual-studio-2010, web-services

i am making an application using Silverlight. In that application i added one web service and in that web service i have one web method as

```
[WebMethod(Description = "Write buffer log")]     
        public bool WriteLog(System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection<LogBuffer> buffer)
        {
            bool result = true;
            .//Some code here
            return result;
        }
```

But i am getting error as "Cannot serialize member System.Exception.Data of type System.Collections.IDictionary, because it implements IDictionary. "

where LogBuffer class is as

```
namespace WriterLog
{
   [DataContract]
    public class LogBuffer
    {
       [DataMember]
        public string Message
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
        [DataMember]
        public Exception Exception
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
        [DataMember]
        public LogType LogType
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
        [DataMember]
        public string MethodName
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
        [DataMember]
        public string DeclaringType
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
        [DataMember]
        public DateTime LogTime
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
    }
}
```

Please help me.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Silverlight version of ObservableCollection is not serializeable
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604(v=vs.95).aspx

Instead try using Generic List. Here's something i use and it works

```
[DataContractAttribute]
public class InstrumentDataField : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
    [DataMemberAttribute]
    private string Value { get; set; }

    [DataMemberAttribute]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public InstrumentDataField(string field, string value)
    {
        this.Name = field;
        this.Value = value;
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

usage

```
[OperationContract]
public List<InstrumentDataField> GetInstrumentData(string browserid, long tickCount)
{
    //some code here
}
```

Comment: Thanks for Reply but instead of System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection<LogBuffer>   I used System.Collections.Generic.List<LogBuffer>  But still i am getting same error.

Comment: Remember that Silverlight doesn't like normal webservices etc. There is an option Add >> New >> Silverlight Webservice

Comment: I am not using Silverlight Webservice( WCF service). I am using normal web service in silverlight application.

Comment: you are asking for trouble... good luck with that http://www.bing.com/search?q=silverlight+asmx+Generic+List&qs=n&form=QBRE&pq=silverlight+asmx+generic+list